# Undefined control sequence. \Begin in algorithmx package

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I have installed and include the required packages but it still gives me the error. Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Mesh Reader}\label{reader}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{mesh\_reader}{}
        \State chunk\_size = rows/total threads
        \Begin
        \State Parallel region   
        \For {each row in mesh}
        \State create node object
        \State assign coordinates of node
        \EndFor
        \End
        \For{ each Element in mesh}
        \If {Element is of \textbf{EDGE} type}
        \State create Edge object
        \State assign node id and other properties to Edge
        \State add Edge object to \textbf{Element list}
        \If{Edge lies on Dirichlet boundary}
        \State Add Edge node id to Dirichlet boundary list
        \EndIf
        \ElsIf{Element is of $\Delta$ type}
        \State create Triangle object
        \State assign node id and other properties to $\Delta$
        \State add $\Delta$ object to \textbf{Element list}
        \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What should that `\Begin` and `\End` do in the algorithm? Comment them out/delete them and you can compile without errors ...

Comment: @Mensch I want to use begin and end command. It will start a block with bold `begin` and end it with bold `End`

Comment: Hm, but there is no need for a separat begin/end ... Or do you mean to call another procedure defined later on? Without any condition for the starting `\Begin`/`\End` an stand-alone `\Begin`/`\End` makes syntactical no sense ... Therefore the correct error message ... Please explain better what concret you want to get (how to do that is then another question with perhaps surprising solutions ...)

Comment: @Mensch `\Begin` and `\End` command is provided by algorithmx package I have read the manual. I want to use it to tell from here my parallel region is started

Comment: @RamiFar please post a full minimal example instead of this sniplet, then we all know what we are dealing with (preamble and document class).

Comment: BTW ctan does not know any packages called algorithmx so your title is also misleading. Did you mean algorithmicx?

Comment: Looking at the algorithmicx manual, note that the `\Begin` `\End`  syntax is only a part of a spefic algorithm layout and it is not clear whether or not you are loading this layout.

Comment: @daleif I have included `algpseudocode` which is used for this

Comment: If you read the manual, algpseudocode does not provide that macro pair, algpascal does. Perhaps you should look in section 4 and define them for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand you right one possibility for you is to define a new procedure like

```
    \Procedure{parallelProcess}{mesh}
    \State Parallel region   
    \For {each row in mesh}
    \State create node object
    \State assign coordinates of node
    \EndFor
    \EndProcedure
```

You can use for example

```
\State \Call{parallelProcess}{mesh}
```

to call thi procedure in your algorithm.

Please see the complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Mesh Reader}\label{reader}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{parallelProcess}{mesh} % <===========================
        \State Parallel region   
        \For {each row in mesh}
        \State create node object
        \State assign coordinates of node
        \EndFor
        \EndProcedure
        \Procedure{mesh\_reader}{}
        \State chunk\_size = rows/total threads
        \State \Call{parallelProcess}{mesh} % <=========================
        \For{ each Element in mesh}
        \If {Element is of \textbf{EDGE} type}
        \State create Edge object
        \State assign node id and other properties to Edge
        \State add Edge object to \textbf{Element list}
        \If{Edge lies on Dirichlet boundary}
        \State Add Edge node id to Dirichlet boundary list
        \EndIf
        \ElsIf{Element is of $\Delta$ type}
        \State create Triangle object
        \State assign node id and other properties to $\Delta$
        \State add $\Delta$ object to \textbf{Element list}
        \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting algorithmn]